# .blend file size much larger after OpenGL Render

Tags: blend-files, opengl, memory-management

I am working on a detailed dialogue scene that is 600 mb. It is a very complex scene, with each part in single layers. I know that is a very big file size, but what my machine can handle it. What worries me is the fact that it grows to 1.2 gb after I do an opengl OpenGL render. I am not concerned with the original 600 mb file size, is their Is there something that I'm missing that makes the file so big. It is a very complex scene, but i have each part in single layers. large?

Edit:I now figured out that when i bake the hair physics, it increases the file size, not the opengl.

Comment: Wait, do you mean the size on disk after resaving the file is bigger, or just the memory use reported in the statusbar-thing?

Comment: I mean the size of the .blend file on the disk

Comment: could you post your .blend to http://www.pasteall.org/blend

Comment: @user9626 please do not edit your questions into the answer to your question but instead post an answer. This will help future users with the same problem?

Comment: @ComradeVader Sorry, my mistake. I'm new to posting questions here.

Comment: @user9626 Welcome. You can answer the question by pressing _Answer Own Question_ below.