# File becomes exponentially bigger after adding 2 objects and remains that big after removing them

Tags: export

I'm working on a large city model, the .obj file is 45MB, when i export it in .kn5 format (for a videogame) the file is about 900MB heavy and everything is fine. But when a add some grass (for a total of 2-3MB) and a couple of big planes (10mb) the .kn5 exported is suddenly 3.75GB heavy and when i remove those 2 things that i added, the size of the exported file goes down to 3.6GB.
The difference is exactly the size of the things that i added (then removed) wich doesn't make any sense to me because now I have 2 identical .kn5 maps but one is 900mb while the other one is 3.6gb, and everytime i export that file (after adding and removing those 2 things) it will always be 3.6GB.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: That has something to do with the exporting and is most likely a bug.

Comment: Looks strange but adding grass means (i guess) particles. Particles themselves are not so heavy but exporting them will make them "real" meshes, this can be very heavy. Can't say why the size doesn't go down as much as it should, some hidden thing are not deleted. check the outliner for more info about that.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21273/blend-file-size-much-larger-after-opengl-render